# Is there any way to access an unrecognized usb device?

Tags: windows-7, usb

Recently I purchased an MP3 player. I copied some files in it. But when I plugged it for second time => USB Device Not Recognized. I know there is lots of usb device repair programs available, but first of all this device should have a drive letter at first! My questions:
1- Do you know a good software for my usb device?
2- Is there any way to access (create label) an unrecognized usb device?
My player is Kenwood with sino wealth chipset.
The player itself is ok, I can not add or remove any files to it. Also there is no special settings in the player.

Comment: Yeah, find the driver for the device and install it.  The real problem comes when the device doesn't have a driver (supposed to be mass storage device, for example)

Comment: Doesn't have any.

Comment: definitely try plugging it into another machine, see if it works there.  What's the exact model of the MP3 player?